# Sdm maxent enmeval 'unused argument (kfolds = 10)'

Tags: maxent

I am currently trying to make a biosfile prior to running maxent but keep getting faced with this error: I wonder if anyone has faced this issue before and fixed it please?

```
bg <- xyFromCell(dens.ras2speciesocc,
      sample(which(!is.na(values(subset(env, 1)))), 10000,
  prob=values(dens.ras2speciesocc)[!is.na(values(subset(env, 1)))])) -- this runs fine and then: 

enmeval_resultsspeciesocc <- ENMevaluate(speciesocc, env,
                                           method= "randomkfold", kfolds = 10, algorithm='maxent.jar', bg.coords = bg)
```

---

**Which returns this error:**

```
'Error in ENMevaluate(speciesocc, env, method = "randomkfold", kfolds = 10,  : 
  unused argument (kfolds = 10)'
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

from [link](https://rdrr.io/cran/ENMeval/man/ENMevaluate.html):

> *occ, env, bg.coords, RMvalues, fc, occ.grp, bg.grp, method, bin.output, rasterPreds, clamp, progbar*:
> These arguments from previous versions are backward-compatible to avoid unnecessary errors for older scripts, but in a later version these arguments will be permanently deprecated.

Comment: Generally an answer should be more than pointing to a link. Are you sure it is relevant? The error message is about `kfold` parameter which is not mentioned here.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and then removed the kfolds argument to see if the default (kfolds=5) would run and I got this message instead:

```
    Error in ENMevaluate(occ, env, method = "randomkfold", algorithm = "maxent.jar",  : 
    Datasets "occs" and "bg" have different column names. Please make them identical and try again.
```

Then I checked my bg column and it was 'x' and 'y' instead of 'longitude' and 'latitude' that I had for my occ file.

That didn't solve it - it went back to giving me the initial error message - but I am sure it was also contributing to the problem!

BUT THEN,

I looked into RMvalue(regularisation multipliers) and fc (feature class) and added them to the code, like this:

```
    enmeval_results <- ENMevaluate(occ, env, bg.coords = bg, method = 'randomkfold',
                           RMvalues = seq(0.5, 4, 0.5),
                           fc = c("L", "LQ", "H", "LQH", "LQHP", "LQHPT"),
                           algorithm='maxent.jar')
```

and it worked! Obviously, change the fc and RMvalues to what suits you best.
I hope this works for you too!
Angeliki